# Prevent background repeat on larger image height in slider

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS3 slider and it works perfectly except on mobile when the height is larger. The problem is that it keeps repeating along `y` and I cannot seem to find where the problem is. I tried using `background: cover` and it still doesn't fix the problem.

Here is the code snippet for the slider:

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="images/eg1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/eg2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/eg3.jpg" alt="">   
    <img src="images/eg2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/eg1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/eg1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/eg2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/eg3.jpg" alt="">   
    <img src="images/eg2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/eg1.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#slider { 
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 100vh;
}
div#slider figure img { 
    width: 20%; 
    float: left; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div#slider figure { 
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 15s slidy infinite; 
}
```

Here's a link to the site if you would like to see how it looks like on responsive view (768x1024 for example):
http://sabirmb.com/Parallax

Thanks

Comment: not seeing the link?

Comment: You can't set repeat or background-size on an image.

Comment: @GhostEcho Added the link. Thanks for pointing this out.